# Angular select - execute change function when option selected even if its the same option

Tags: angular

I have a select with options:

```
<select (change)="myFunction(fcName)"
        formControlName="{{ fcName }}" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let type of form.choices[fcName]" [ngValue]="type.id">{{ type.text }}</option>
</select>
```

Sorry code is not the easiest to read but **it works fine**. However, I want `myFunction` to execute, even if the selected option is the current option.

I understand why `(change)` does not work since there is no change if the same option is selected. `(click)` fires too frequently. Is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(click)` should do the job but instead of placing it on the `select` element, add it to the `option` element.

```
<select formControlName="{{ fcName }}" class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let type of form.choices[fcName]" [ngValue]="type.id" (click)="onClickFunction(type)">{{ type.text }}</option>
</select>
```